# sending mail from localhost using mail() function

Tags: php

i am using Xampp on windows 7 and i am trying to send a mail using php mail() function to my gmail. (without using libraries like  [Phpmailer](https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer))

i have tried using:

1. **Mercury Mail** - The script is not showing any errors and the mail() function actually          returns true
2. **[Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/)** - same issue as mercury mail
3. **[Fake Send mail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/)** - getting a "Connect timed out" error.

These are my settings for Fake Send Mail :

**sendmail.ini**

```
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587  (tried using 465)
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=fromname@gmail.com
auth_password=pass
```

**php.ini**

```
sendmail_path = "\"E:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t" has been commented out
```

This is my code:

```
<?php

$to      = 'toname@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the the';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: fromname@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: fromname@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

This is result of telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 :

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP sb3sm19649093pac.14 - gsmtp
451 4.4.2 Timeout - closing connection. sb3sm19649093pac.14 - gsmtp
Connection to host lost.
```

i have gone through similar questions in this forum but it's still not working for me.

**What is it that i am missing here and could you provide me the links for any other tools that i should try? Thanks..**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the mail command, its quite unstable on windows and should in fact not even be used on Linux. You should use the [PHPMailer Class](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) by Worx of [PHPMailerLite](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) class. This connects to the SMTP Server.

It's giving you a lot of extra options. You should try implementing the PHPMailer class for you own sake!

Comment: phpmailer is working for me... what i wanted to know was why the mail() function is not working

Comment: Probably because the windows sendmail wont authenticate on smtp, and is not able to connect to secure smtp servers. Which gmail is required to connect through.